# SPWeb.getFile(Url) exception : value does not fall within the expected range still again

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a problem of

> value does not fall within the expected range

from below code.

```
 string webUrl = "/_layouts/15/wfcourrierdep/ArticlesList.aspx";
 string fullpath = SPUtility.GetFullUrl(SPContext.Current.Site,webUrl);           
 SPFile file = web.GetFile(fullpath);
```

What can the cause be?

Comment: Is your "webUrl" a server relative URL on your site or a Site relative URL?

Comment: site relative: the whole url is http://servername:port/sites/sitename/_layouts/15/wfcourrierdep/ArticlesList.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please update your "webUrl" variable to be Server Relative. webUrl = "/sites/sitename/_layouts/15/wfcourrierdep/ArticlesList.aspx";

```
string fullpath = SPUtility.GetFullUrl(SPSite, serverRelativeURL);
```

Reference
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getfullurl(v=office.15).ASPX